# java System.getProperties().put();

Tags: java, properties, system

I work with a old project and have the following line :

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
```

Does this line change the system property http.proxyHost?

Comment: You can check by another `getProperties` immediately afterwards. Please report back.

Answer (score 2):

It does not change the system properties outside of you program.

`System.getProperties()` returns a `Properties` object. Every call to the `getProperties()` method returns the identical object.

But you can add or overwrite properties within this object and that is done with the call to `put`.

So in effect, in your program the value returned by `System.getProperties().get("http.proxyHost")`is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only modify the returned object from System.getProperties() call.
But it seems that the next callers uses the same properties object. So, the answer is yes.

Comment: The Javadoc (which could be clearer to be sure) makes it sound as if that object is a singleton that will also be returned to subsequent callers.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Thilo. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works:

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "1.2.3.4");
String x = (String) System.getProperties().get("http.proxyHost");
System.out.println(x); // prints 1.2.3.4
```